# condensing rows in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
SELECT case when t1.state != 1 then 'no' else 'yes' end as state,
       convert(date, t1.date, 101), 
       t2.name, 
       t2.descript,
       count(t2.runs) as runs,
       SUM(t2.pass) as pass
FROM my_table1 t1 (NOLOCK)
LEFT OUTER JOIN my_table2 t2 (NOLOCK) on t1.name = t2.name
GROUP BY t2.name, t1.date, t2.descript, t1.state
```

Above is my query

The issue I am having is that rows are not condensing to show a total sum of their values. You may ask about the description, they are the same throughout the list of values I am looking at. Just not sure why my values are not condensing. I am using Microsoft's SQL Server Management Studio.

The output I am receiving looks like so: 
[image]

Comment: Your query should give syntax error - you are using aggregate functions, but no grouping.

Comment: @Arvo my mistake on the group by, edited question to include group by

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an aggregation, presumably:

```
SELECT (case when t1.state <> 1 then 'no' else 'yes' end) as state,
       convert(date, t1.date, 101), 
       t2.name, 
       t2.descript,
       count(t2.runs) as runs,
       SUM(t2.pass) as pass
FROM my_table1 t1 (NOLOCK) LEFT OUTER JOIN
     my_table2 t2 (NOLOCK) 
     ON t1.name = t2.name
GROUP BY (case when t1.state <> 1 then 'no' else 'yes' end),
         convert(date, t1.date, 101), name, descript;
```

Comment: @Gordon, Dont you think only this will do trick for us - `GROUP BY t1.state, t1.date, name, descript`

Comment: @Gordon Having the (case when..) and convert(date...) gave the result that I needed. Appreciate it

Comment: @YogeshSharma . . . `<>` is the original SQL operator for not equals.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai . . . No, you will get a row for each distinct `state` that is not "1".

Comment: @GordonLinoff, take a Bow. God of SQL.